# Regex MySQL - Match First Two letters, x Numbers

Tags: mysql, regex

Looking to match any rows in a MySQL database where VectorId starts with 'TS' followed by any amount of numbers, min 1. I want to match TS1, TS1234, etc but not TS (by itself), T12 or V124.

So far I have:

```
SELECT * FROM T3_SeriesInfo WHERE VectorId LIKE '^TS\d+' ORDER BY VectorId DESC
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the manual? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Something like this:

`SELECT * FROM T3_SeriesInfo WHERE VectorId REGEXP '^TS[[:digit:]]+' ORDER BY VectorId DESC`

Comment: Didn't realize the regexp syntax was completely different than most things. Got it

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM T3_SeriesInfo WHERE VectorId REGEXP '^TS\d*' ORDER BY VectorId DESC
```

Comment: Gah, didnt realise it took me so long to find the answer.. getting rusty :)